# Align two elements

Tags: jquery

I have the following on a plugin:

```
$(this).mouseenter(function (e) {
  var this = $(this);
  var text = "<div class="Text">" + options.Text + "</div>"
  $("body").append(text);
})
```

How to align "text" to "this" before adding it to body on the following positions:
TopCenter, BottomCenter, RightMiddle or LeftMiddle.

Thank You!

Comment: You should'nt overwrite reserved keywords like `this` !

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).on('mouseenter', function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        text  = $('<div />', {'class': 'text',
                              text   : options.Text,
                              style  : 'position   : relative;  
                                        margin     : 0 auto; 
                                        text-align : center;'
                             }
                 );
    $("body").append(text);
}):
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You should not use "this" as the local parameter because thats a reserved javascript word.
2. You can add a style in div to align the text.

   ```
   var $this = $(this); 
   $this.mouseenter(function (e) {
      var text = "<div class='Text' style='text-align:left'>" + options.Text + "</div>"
      $("body").append(text);
   });
   ```

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain myself correctly. $(this) will be an anchor. And div is a tooltip. So I would like the tooltip to be aligned to the anchor which generated it, when clicked. I have the following http://codepen.io/shapper/pen/pbvnG. At the moment the tooltip is being moved according to the mouse. I am looking to add an option where the tooltip does not move and where I have an option to make it aligned to the anchor on one of the position that I described. Am I explaining it correctly?